# How to differentiate between two different errors with the same error code?

Tags: linux, sockets, pthreads, error-code, errno

Reading through the Linux man page, I sometimes encounter functions that can return/set the same error code for two distinct errors. Some examples are:

- [`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) can return both `EAGAIN` and `EAGAIN`.
- [`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) can return both `EINVAL` and `EINVAL`.
- [`socket`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) and [`bind`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) can set `errno` to both `EINVAL` and `EINVAL`.

There are more examples (like [`send`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) can set `EAGAIN` and `EAGAIN` and [`bind`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) can set `EADDRINUSE` and `EADDRINUSE`, but they seem to depend on whether you're using datagram sockets or not and thus one can figure out the correct error based on the context).

How is it meant I should differentiate between these errors?

Comment: The pthread function return these errors (as the man page says) - I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. socket(2) and bind(2) return -1 and set `errno` (again as the man page says).

Comment: @root `socket` and `bind` both return `-1` on error; that is true. But on error, they can set `errno` to `EINVAL` even though two different errors have occurred. My question is how I'm supposed to differentiate between those two errors when they both set `errno` to the same value. Can I do it based on some context? Can I do it with the help of a function? Is there some secret I don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general way to differentiate between these conditions.

Sometimes the man page will specify conditions that you could check, but that's it.

You should design what you're building such that the differences you're trying to detect wouldn't matter. For example, if you get `EAGAIN`, just try again later (or return something to the client that would cause it to try again).

Comment: That's quite unsatisfactory if it's true. The problem I have isn't about the design of the application. For example, if a thread cannot join it cannot join. The application doesn't care about the reason and handles it properly but I, as a programmer, want to have feedback of exactly what's going wrong. Accidentally creating detachable threads that I'm trying to join versus having another thread that's waiting to join with the current thread, requires substantial different solutions.

Comment: I'll wait a while to see if someone else has a solution. It feels like something so fundamental that I can't imagine it to be the case that there's no way to differentiate between them.

Comment: I share your sentiment. As you can see here: https://github.com/walac/glibc/blob/master/nptl/pthread_join.c, your best bet is to add debug code that checks the specific condition (in this case, whether or not the thread is detached).

Comment: Too many things can go wrong; it's unreasonable to get an individualized error number for each. E.g. IME `EINVAL` almost always means a programming error. But, there are loads of specific reasons. Say, an invalid buffer address: by your argument shouldn't the system tell you exactly how/why it's invalid? Maybe the buffer address is in code space; maybe it's read-only data, maybe it's unallocated space, maybe it points into kernel virtual address space; maybe the beginning is valid but it extends too far. IMO, it's a benefit that the kernel sticks things into buckets of similar errors.

Comment: I think he's expecting something like specific error messages, the way exceptions in other languages can have. And I suspect the reason such a thing is _not_ implemented is because it might encourage people to e.g. try to allocate memory (in C) for an error description when raising errors.